# Linux: panel with mac-like menubar functionality?

Tags: linux, taskbar, desktop, gnome-panel

I'm playing with my desktop appearance at the moment, and I would really like to save some vertical space.

At the moment there is the Xfce top taskbar, the Firefox titlebar filling up space and the rest (e.g. content).

I'd like to merge the titlebar (and maybe the menus) with the taskbar or lose it. I know this won't work on Xfce, but maybe one of you knows a desktop environment that already has that feature. Something with GTK+ client side decorations would be nice.

Googling `linux smart taskbar` and similar things did not yield any results for me.

Additional edit: I just found out, that the taskbar in MacOSX is called menubar and in Linux (at least with Gnome and Xfce) the taskbars name is panel.

Comment: Not completely what you want but worth looking at: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/htitle/ - For newer Firefox, see this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/6sjlme/any_alternatives_to_htitle_for_firefox/

Comment: Thanks, but hiding the titlebar on maximize isn't what I'm looking for.
The Firefox example is a bit misleading as I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you basically want Ubuntu.

Comment: As I never have used Ubuntu I can't tell.